# Instantiate object choosing between different concrete implementations of ABC

Tags: python, abstract-class

In my code, I currently have a class `Obj`, implementing some low-level functionality, nothing fancy in it. Now, I need to add a second implementation of `Obj`. Which implementation is instantiated should be decided based on some properties, to be checked at instantiation time.

The solution I came up with is to have an abstract class `_absObj`, and two implementations of it, `_Obj1` and `_Obj2`. I still want to present, at the API level, only one `Obj` class, so I re-implemented `Obj` simply like this:

```
class Obj:
    __new__(cls, stuff):
        if _check_something(stuff):
            return _Obj1(stuff)
        else:
            return _Obj2(stuff)
```

This works fine, but I see a few inconveniences:

- [minor] `Obj` has no documented methods. Probably this is actually an advantage.
- [major] `Obj` is not a subclass of `absObj`, even if every object instantiated from it derives from the abstract class.
- [major] In tests, I need to often mock `Obj`, but I cannot mock any of its methods, it has none! I can only mock one of its implementations, which is fragile, as I may change the implementation, or the implementation instantiated may change.

Is there any smarter solution? If the solution implies dumping some of the oop noise, even better.

Comment: A possible solution is to add a classmethod to `Obj`, which decides which implementation is instantiated. Not sure, however, if that is any good.

Comment: Shouldn't all the documentation for `_Obj1` and `_Obj2` be covered by the `_absObj` documentation? To me it would make more sense to have some kind of factory class method in `_absObj` rather than override `__new__`. You could also have `Obj` drive from `_absObj` so that users know what to expect from `Obj` instances.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like so. `AbsObj` would be the only "public" class. Its implementations would be chosen and returned by `AbsObj#create`.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbsObj(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        '''Document this.'''
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def create(stuff):
        '''
        All the user needs to know is that create returns an AbsObj.
        The specific implementation shouldn't matter.
        '''
        if stuff:
            return Obj1(stuff)
        else:
            return Obj2(stuff)

class Obj1(AbsObj):
    def foo(self):
        print('number 1')

class Obj2(AbsObj):
    def foo(self):
        print('number 2')

AbsObj.create(True).foo
AbsObj.create(False).foo
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is as follows:

```
class Obj(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f1(...):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def f1(...):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def factory(stuff):
        if _check_something(stuff):
             return _Obj1(stuff)
        else:
             return _Obj2(stuff)
```

Where `_Obj1` and `_Obj2` derive from `Obj` itself. This actually works, even if I am not really sure of all the implications.

Comment: I think you'll be fine with @axblount  's and your answer, that are essentially the same. The important thing is probably an abstract one, client code only uses the factory method and the abstract interface. It shouldn't depend on what kind of implementation was retrieved.

Comment: Yes, I think this is reasonable, even if I find it somehow over-complicated. I guess it's just oop.